# merge arrays in bigquery that have one common value

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

In big query I have a table with one column with is an array of strings.
The data will look like this :

```
['a','b']
['b','c']
['c', 'd']
['e']
```

Now my desired output is :

```
['a','b','c','d']
['e']
```

Basically I want to merge all the array that have at least one value in common.

Any way I can do that?

thanks

Comment: This looks like you want to walk down a path in a graph.  In SQL that is normally done using a recursive CTE and BQ does not support recursive CTEs -- or other built-in functionality that does this.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought also. Using a recursive query would work.
I was just wondering how we could do that in BQ...
Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this type of logic is implemented using so called recursive CTEs, but BigQuery does not support such!

Luckily, recently introduced [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) functionality allows to implement this in BigQuery

So, below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS WITH input AS (
  SELECT ['a', 'b'] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ['b', 'c'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['c', 'd'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['x', 'y'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['y', 'a'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['e'] 
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val ) arr FROM input;

LOOP
  SET rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt);
  SET run_away_stop = run_away_stop + 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ttt AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM ttt t1, ttt t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(arr, ',') arr FROM ttt;
```

with final output

```
Row arr  
1   a,b,c,d,x,y  
2   e
```

Above took 3 iterations. In real life example it obviously will take more  - so yo need to adjust max allowed iterations - currently it is 10 (see last statement within the LOOP)

Note: most likely above can be optimized - leaving this up to you

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery now supports Recursive CTEs.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/recursive-ctes

So, borrowing some of the strategy from Mikhail, I put this together.  (I also expanded the sample data to ensure it handled other test cases correctly.)

```
WITH RECURSIVE input AS (
  SELECT ['a', 'b'] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ['b', 'c'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['c', 'd'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['x', 'y'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['y', 'a'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['e'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['m', 'n'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['n', 'm']
), preprocessed AS (
  -- drops dupes and sorts each array; this is necessary for the ['e', 'f'], ['f', 'e'] case
  SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr 
  FROM input 
), accumulated AS (
  -- recursively accumulate intersecting arrays
  SELECT arr, 1 AS run FROM preprocessed 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr,
    t2.run + 1 AS run
  FROM preprocessed t1, accumulated t2
  -- where at least one common element, but not every element in the first
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) 
         BETWEEN 1 AND ARRAY_LENGTH(t1.arr) -1 
), max_run_by_item AS (
  -- gets the final run index for each item in any array
  SELECT DISTINCT item, run
  FROM accumulated, UNNEST(arr) item
  QUALIFY MAX(run) OVER(PARTITION BY item) = run
), finally AS (
  -- reduce down to the distinct final run arrays
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(a.arr) arr
  FROM max_run_by_item mr
  JOIN accumulated a USING(run)
  WHERE a.arr[0] = mr.item -- more efficient than WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(a.arr) AS x WHERE x = mr.item)
  GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', a.arr) -- this, along with the ANY_VALUE serves the purpose of SELECT DISTINCT but in the case of an array
)
SELECT FORMAT('%t', arr) AS arr -- nice format of array for inspection
FROM finally
```

Note that the final selection formats it as a string for ease of viewing, so skip that step if you need the array.